# How do I read all of the current faces being sent to OpenGL for rendering

Tags: c++, c, opengl, 3d, buffer

I have an old program that I want to read the mesh data from, is there a way I can access all the faces/triangle strips that any program(not just the one doing the reading) is sending to OpenGL's buffer.

Comment: The answer will be likely platform dependent, what OS are you targeting?

Comment: A little more info about the "old program" and what it does would probably be helpful. Also, have you tried anything so far?

Comment: The OS I want to run the program on is Windows XP professional, the "old program" is a game that was made forever ago, and has since been dropped support on, and I want the meshes for nostalgia, and to archive them for future posterity, I don't mind having to re-weld all the faces together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [glintercept](http://code.google.com/p/glintercept/)

```
GLIntercept is a OpenGL function call interceptor for Windows that will intercept and log all OpenGL calls.
```

Comment: Looks like what I wanted, :-) I'll investigate more, thanks for the help